# Monitor MySQL activity per database?

Tags: mysql, monitoring

What is the best way to monitor activity on each database of my server ?

I tried mtop/mytop which display activity in real time but aren't very practical to see all the queries executed on it.

I activated MySQL logs but there's no option to split them per database.

What tools are you using to monitor MySQL servers ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I try to stay away from having multiple databases in one instance. Instead I have multiple instances set up on a server where each one is dedicated to a database.

[MySQL Cacti templates](http://code.google.com/p/mysql-cacti-templates/wiki/MySQLTemplates) are a good monitoring solution. If you are enterprise customer then [MySQL Enterprise Monitor](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/monitor.html) works. Also check out [mycheckpoint](http://code.openark.org/forge/mycheckpoint) from openark.

**EDIT**
Here are some tutorials for setting up multiple instances on one server:

- [Running multiple instances of MySQL on the same machine](http://www.ducea.com/2009/01/19/running-multiple-instances-of-mysql-on-the-same-machine/)
- [How-to: Setup Multiple MySQL Instances](http://gomysql.com/2010/10/how-to-setup-multiple-mysql-instances/)

You could also use [MySQL Sandbox](http://mysqlsandbox.net/) as it automates a lot of different set ups for you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, do you have a quick tutorial to set up multiple instances per server ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to understand where most of the tools you are using are getting their data from - `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`.  This data simply is not available broken down on a database level inside MySQL.

MySQL 5.5, 5.6 and Percona Server have been doing a great job of improving the diagnostics available to you with features like [performance_schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/performance-schema.html) and [userstats](http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/percona-server%3afeatures%3auserstatv2) - but I don't know of any GUI/monitoring tools that are taking advantage yet.

I recommend installing Percona Server, and taking a look at table_statistics:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STATISTICS
   WHERE TABLE_NAME='tables_priv';
+--------------+-------------------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------------+
| TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME                    | ROWS_READ | ROWS_CHANGED | ROWS_CHANGED_X_INDEXES |
+--------------+-------------------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------------+
| mysql        | tables_priv                   |         2 |            0 |                      0 | 
+--------------+-------------------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------------+
```