# How to do MySQL User Accounting

Tags: mysql, security, logs, maatkit

I can't seem to find any information on this anywhere. I found a question here called [Monitor MySQL activity per database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7620/monitor-mysql-activity-per-database) but that's not quite the answer either.

I'd like to be able to log the following to a system log somewhere, preferably via syslog:

- User (not master/slave) login
- User logout
- User connect time
- User IP

Something similar to `last` and `lastb` for MySQL. Can this be done? Is anything already written and in the Ubuntu and Red Hat Enterprise Linux repositories? Can MaatKit do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your only recourse would be to activate the slow log and use it as a MyISAM table. By default, the slow log would normally be a text file. However, a general_log table was provided in newer release of MySQL as a CSV table.

```
mysql> use mysql
Database changed
mysql> show create table slow_log\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: slow_log
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `slow_log` (
  `start_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `query_time` time NOT NULL,
  `lock_time` time NOT NULL,
  `rows_sent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rows_examined` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `db` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `last_insert_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `insert_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sql_text` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  KEY `start_time` (`start_time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Slow log'
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql>
```

Make sure you have this in my.cnf and then restart mysql if you had to add this:

```
[mysqld]
log-output=TABLE
log-slow-queries
long-query-time=0.00001
```

Next, convert the table to MyISAM and index it on the needed columns:

```
SET @old_log_state = @@global.slow_query_log;
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'OFF';
ALTER TABLE mysql.slow_log ENGINE = MyISAM;
ALTER TABLE mysql.slow_log ADD INDEX starttime_index (start_time);
ALTER TABLE mysql.slow_log ADD INDEX db_starttime_index (db,start_time);
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = @old_log_state;
SHOW CREATE TABLE mysql.slow_log\G
```

You can query the table and retrieve the user and host from mysql.slow_log column user_host.

You can crontab some tasks to copy the data from mysql.slow_log where you need it, may a separate database.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mystatus;
```

Perhaps, you can run queries like this:

```
SET @old_log_state = @@global.slow_query_log;
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'OFF';
ALTER TABLE mysql.slow_log RENAME mystats.slow_log;
CREATE TABLE mysql.slow_log LIKE mystats.slow_log;
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = @old_log_state;
```

This will move the slow log elsewhere and start with an empty one.

This may not be a full answer, but I hope this is useful to you as to some direction to take.

Comment: Interesting! Fantastic and well-written detailed description. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't necessarily useful in my case (unfortunately) because the user logging in is also being used by the system application - unless I rule out the user running on localhost (hmmm...) I also note that the slow log time is fractional; I thought that was either introduced in a newer version of MySQL or was solely available from Percona as a patch or as part of their MySQL build.

Comment: You saw [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7989/3703) and commented positively on it. Do you think it will work for my purposes?

Comment: @David : That answer from DTest may be just what you need. However, keep in mind that it will increase disk I/O very slightly and slow down the recording of binary log events with any surge of DB Connections. In a low-to-moderately trafficked site, this may not be a problem.